# Redirect all the .html files to old site with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all the files that end with .html to a the old site folder, currently my htaccess looks as follows:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        # RedirectMatch 302 /(.+?).html$ http://superawesomedomain.com/old/$1.html [L]
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>`

But with my condition `RedirectMatch 302` when I apply it gets to http://superawesomedomain.com/old/old/old/old/old/old...old/old/old...old/old/old/ until it breaks the browser :(

Any ideas on how to make the redirection?

Thank you!

Comment: the problem is the loop, it find always an html so continue to redirect till browser crash

Comment: redirectmatch isn't part of mod_rewrite, therefore the `[L]` means nothing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!old/).+?\.html)$ /old/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

- Don't use `RedirectMatch` with other `mod_rewrite` rules
- Make sure you're not redirecting when URI already starts with `/old/` to stop redirection loop